# Thread Starts lags UI WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

Well, I've been struggling with this for a while and I've been unable to find a solution.
I'm developing one of those cashier apps you see in the supermarket where everything works fast as hell. The cashiers know the program so good they just type at the speed of light so the UI must be incredibly responsive.

Anyway, as I've only coded in WPF I'm using it, if someone says WinForms is faster I'll surely learn it.
This is my code, it's very simple as I'm testing performance

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Thread t;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        t = new Thread(HandleThread);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void HandleThread()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Whenever the button is clicked, a new thread is launched as I plan on connecting to a server in the new thread.
My problem is the method `button_Click` is VERY SLOW. It takes about 1 second to return so the button looks like it's stuck and the application look sluggish. I've tried threads, `BackgroundWorker`, changed the framework to 4.0 and tried `Tasks`. NOTHING. Whatever I do to start some kind of background work the method takes forever.

I need to check the username and password on a remote server, how can I accomplish it without hurting the UI?

Comment: If the code as posted in your question indeed needs about 1sec for the Button_Click handler, then on what meager hardware is it running on?

Comment: Does this happen every time or only the first time the button is clicked? Could be JIT compilation although unlikely.

Comment: Its running on a Windows 7, Intel Core I7 8GB Ram, SSD.
It only happens the first time, if I click it again it works as it should. The problem is the person clicking it won't click it again as It's supposed to login.

Comment: Does the effect only happen when running in the debugger or also when you run it standalone? (when running in a debugger, you will need to account for the debugger loading symbol files, perhaps)

Comment: Start this using a background thread , you are just locking the ui for 3 sec. , i don't even understand what the question here is ..

Comment: @eran, what? Where is he locking the UI for 3 seconds...?

Comment: he clicks a button and starts a 3 sec. thread sleep

Comment: @eran, read the code carefully, and you might stumble over Thread.Start ;)

Comment: Have you profiled the App as Release build? Have you considered using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)?

Comment: @elgonzo that's what i'm saying he starts a thread which sleeps for 3 seconds

Comment: @eran, okay, yes. I was just replying because you wrote "locking the **UI**", which the code doesn't do :)

Comment: oo .. i forgot i wrote that good thing we back and forth'd on it for 2 days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should turn off the IntelliTrace ([`How-To`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264948%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
2. In the Options dialog box, expand the IntelliTrace node and then click General.
3. Clear the Enable IntelliTrace check box.
4. Click OK.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this should help? Normally IntelliTrace doesn't slow down execution to *this* extent. If it is, the true reason might be a large number of exceptions thrown, so simply turning IT off could just hide but not solve the problem.

Comment: @pbalaga I do not know why either, but it did my problems with WPF as well.

Comment: @CristianEduardoLehuedeLyon also, Ctrl-F5, or just non-debugging wont have this trouble.

Comment: We are investigating this issue to see if it can be resolved for a future version of Visual Studio. In the meantime, you may wish to just disable 'Gesture' events instead of completely disabling IntelliTrace. To do that go to 'Tools->Options->IntelliTrace->IntelliTrace Events' and disable 'Gesture' collection.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to spawn a new thread every time you click your button? Is this thread long-lived? Do you really want to allocate 1 meg of stack space (on 64 bit OSes) for this every time you click this button? Really sure you don't want to use the TPL's Task and CancellationTokenSource instead?

In your case, you should really not create a thread every time you click, what you want is start a long-running async task and check the result.

```
public void OnClick(object src,EventArgs args)
{
    var login = tbLogin.Text;// assuming non MVVM coding here
    var pwd= tbPass.Text;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
        return _myWebService.CheckAuth(login,pwd); // your login stuff here
    }).ContinueWith(wsTask=>{
       if(!wsTask.IsCompleted){ // handle errors / cancel }
       DisplayLoginState(ws.Result);
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()); // this runs on the UI Thread

}
```