# WPF - how to avoid performace drop when TextBox is focused

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl

I have an application with SharpGL control in it (OpenGL). Whenever TextBox gets focus, SharpGLControl suffers enormous performace drop. Not the FPS of the SharpGLControl, but updating speed of whole GUI.

Code example:

```
<Grid>
    <gl:OpenGLControl x:Name="GLcontrol" DrawFPS="True" OpenGLDraw="OpenGLControl_OpenGLDraw" OpenGLInitialized="OpenGLControl_OpenGLInitialized"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="54"/> //click on this and FPS drop
</Grid>
```

It looks like default reaction to view itself lost focus, but on OpenGL-type controls drawing speed does matter. Is there a way how to override rest of the view drawing logic when a TextBox is focused? (any other controls doesnt seem to cause this)

Sorry, if this is duplicate, but google gives zero hits on those keywords.

Comment: Maybe the problem could be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034865/thread-starts-lags-ui-wpf

Comment: I dont personally think so. It should not be thread related since for any other controls it works (listviews, radiobuttons, buttons, expanders etc...). You v got the point I could draw in other thread BUT the outcome is uncertain - it looks like just the form updating speed droped, not the control iteself. And mutlithreading application is a LOT of additional work.